# HLS m3u8 Download takes a lot of time

Tags: ios, swift, http-live-streaming, m3u8, urlsession

I am trying to download a HLS stream onto my iPhone using apple's documentation mentioned here - https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/MediaPlaybackGuide/Contents/Resources/en.lproj/HTTPLiveStreaming/HTTPLiveStreaming.html

Even small 2 minutes videos are taking about 3-4 mins to download, i am having a fast internet connection so that is not an issue.

What i want to know is there any specific stream i need to download or specify while downloading? The streams in my m3u8 are 320p, 720p, 1080p. Is it downloading all of them so it's taking that much of time?

This is how i am setting up code to download hls -

```
let urlConfiguration = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: downloadIdentifier)

 // Create a new AVAssetDownloadURLSession with background configuration, delegate, and queue
let   assetDownloadSession = AVAssetDownloadURLSession(configuration:   urlConfiguration,
                                                    assetDownloadDelegate: self,
                                                    delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main)

let asset = AVURLAsset(url: URL(string: assetUrl)!)

 // Create new AVAssetDownloadTask for the desired asset
let avAssetDownloadTask = assetDownloadSession?.makeAssetDownloadTask(asset: asset,
                                                                    assetTitle: title,
                                                                    assetArtworkData: nil,
                                                                    options: nil)
 // Start task and begin download
avAssetDownloadTask?.resume()
```

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using a tool like Charles Proxy or Wireshark to determine the throughput of underlying network requests. You may have a slow server.